# Radix Sort: modulo 16 on base 10 numbers

Tags: sorting, radix-sort

Would it be wrong to choose to have 16 buckets to sort a decimal number (base 10) using radix sort? From other questions here on "the best choice of base of numbers" I am guessing it should be okay to do so. But I'm not sure how it would end up working correctly. For example, 16 would be lower than 15 when using n modulo 16 on a base ten number. So, should there be a strict correspondence between the base of the number and the number of buckets?

Comment: Normally numbers are stored in binary, not BCD (binary coded decimal), so base 16 or more commonly base 256 is used for radix sort on integers.

Comment: Well of course 16 would be lower than 15. Just like 10 would be lower than 1 if you were using modulo 10. Are you sure you understand how radix sort works?

Comment: Yes ten would be lower than one. But in the second pass, ten would move to its correct position with modulo 10 whereas the same doesn't happen with modulo 16..

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that 16 would get sorted out in the second pass for modulo 16. Very silly of me. I thought the algorithm stops after the initial pass for this case. So I guess it would be correct to sort decimals using modulo 16 as well.